# Blender paid work

Tags: support, questions, scope

I am planning to have a 3D animation short movies, My question:

Is it considered off-topic to offer some paid work related to Blender, in blender stack exchange?

Comment: maybe you should change "illegal" to "considered off-topic" or "not allowed".

Comment: @Tooniis, updated :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"Legal" yes, I guess so, but it is off topic and would get closed.

Job offers are off topic. We get maybe one a month or so, and they quickly get closed, and directed to [blender artists' job section](https://blenderartists.org/forum/forumdisplay.php?52-Paid-Work).

So to save you from quickly getting your "question" really a job offer DVed and closed, just post on BA, its linked above.